# Загрузка всего списка товаров на сайте

Tags: python, request, beautiful-soup

Здравствуйте, я пишу парсер для сайта на python+beautiful soup4+request.
Страница грузится с 40 товарами, при проматывании вниз подгружаются другие товары, скорее всего с помощью AJAX. Как можно прогрузить страницу со всеми товарами сразу, чтобы разом получить все ссылки на товары? Посоветуйте библиотеки, либо способы как можно это сделать?

Comment: Надо просто открыть в браузере консоль разработчика, проанализировать какие запросы делаются при подгрузке и делать такие же из своего python-кода.

Comment: на тему web-scraping целые книги написаны. Приёмы, которые работают на одних сайтах, не работают на других. Начните с официального (документированного) API для сайта, если нет, посмотрите  есть ли неофициальное (какие запросы javascript делает), если не ясно, то попробуйте ваши действия с браузером автоматизировать, используя selenium webdriver (+ headless chrome). К примеру, чтобы промотать страницу до конца уже подгруженных элементов: `browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")` (после этого нужно подождать пока новые элементы не подгрузятся и повторить).